# How to make a field required Laravel Validation?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have a bunch of inputs on my form, and the field under consideration has various validation requirements. To simplify, I have created an analogy:

I have inputs A, B, C and D. A, B, and C are all array inputs. 'A' should be required if B and C are present, but not required if input 'D' is a value of 1 even if B and C are present. The same requirements are present for inputs 'B' and 'C'.

My initial guess was: A.* => 'required_with:B.*,C.* | required_if:D,0' 
but this doesn't really work.

I'm terrible with custom validation, so if a step-by-step method of a custom validator is needed, can you please provide a full code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is documented on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Validating When Present

In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
]);
```

In the example above, the email field will only be validated if it is present in the $data array.

Complex Conditional Validation

Sometimes you may wish to add validation rules based on more complex conditional logic. For example, you may wish to require a given field only if another field has a greater value than 100. Or, you may need two fields to have a given value only when another field is present. Adding these validation rules doesn't have to be a pain. First, create a Validator instance with your static rules that never change:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'games' => 'required|numeric',
]);
```

Let's assume our web application is for game collectors. If a game collector registers with our application and they own more than 100 games, we want them to explain why they own so many games. For example, perhaps they run a game resale shop, or maybe they just enjoy collecting. To conditionally add this requirement, we can use the sometimes method on the Validator instance.

```
$v->sometimes('reason', 'required|max:500', function ($input) {
    return $input->games >= 100;
});
```

Comment: So would this work: 
`$v = Validator::make($data, [
]); //no rules provided`



`$v->sometimes('A', 'required', function($input){
     
     if ($input->D==1){
         return false;
     };
     if (($input->B !=null) || ($input->C !=null)){
         return true;
     };
}); `

Comment: Easiest way to find out is to test :)